# Loaded data truncated when using nsIFileInputStream & nsIConverterInputStream

Tags: javascript, firefox, xpcom

I'm working on a project (BrowserIO - go to browserio dot googlecode dot com if you want to check out the code and work on it.  Help welcome!) in which I'm using Firefox's nsIFileInputStream in tandem with nsIConverterInputStream, per their example (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I%2F%2FO#Simple), but only a portion of the full data is being loaded.  The code is:

```
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
file.initWithPath(path);
var data = "";

var fstream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-input-stream;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFileInputStream);
var cstream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/intl/converter-input-stream;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIConverterInputStream);

fstream.init(file, -1, 0, 0);
cstream.init(fstream, "UTF-8", 0, 0); // you can use another encoding here if you wish

var str = {};
cstream.readString(-1, str); // read the whole file and put it in str.value
data = str.value;

cstream.close(); // this closes fstream
```

If you want to see this behavior, checkout the code from the BrowserIO project page, and use Firebug to set a breakpoint at the `data = str.value;` line in file_io.js.  Then select a text file from the list, and click the "Open" button.  In Firebug, in the watch panel set a watch for str.value.  Look at the file... It should be truncated, unless it's really short.

For reference, the code above is the main body of the openFile() function in trunk/scripts/file_io.js.

Anybody have any clue what's happening with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [nsIConverterInputStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIConverterInputStream); basically, -1 doesn't mean "give me everything" but rather "give me the default amount", which the docs claim is 8192.

More generally, if you want to exhaust the contents of an input stream, you have to loop until it's empty.  Nothing in any of the stream contracts guarantees that the amount of data returned by a call is the entirety of the contents of the stream; it could even return less than it has immediately available if it wanted.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out after I messed around with it a bit.  The other problem I'm having now is that when I pass the content through converter stream, I have to know the file encoding type ahead of time.  So for example, I have two files: One in UTF-8 and the other in Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1).  If I specify the encoding, it works on only one type of file.  Do you know of any way to access the data directly from the fstream object / nsIFileInputStream?  Browser the MDC docs right now, not finding much...

Comment: Your idea below works, but the value you want isn't a string; it's really more appropriately an array of bytes.  Getting the latter is easy enough and just requires using nsIBinaryInputStream instead of nsIScriptableStream.  Note, however, that nsIScriptableInputStream.read under the hood returns a char*; what if the file contains null bytes?  The C++->JS code has no way of knowing that the char* returned has length greater than strlen would indicate, so you'll get truncated strings if your file contains nulls.  It might not matter here, but it's playing with fire in my book, and I'd avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered how to do the file read without converting, to avoid issues from not knowing the file encoding type. The answer is to use `nsIScriptableInputStream` with `nsIFileInputStream`:

```
var sstream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptableInputStream);
fstream.init(file, 0x01, 0004, 0);
sstream.init(fstream);
data = sstream.read(sstream.available());
```

Comment: From the docs: "Note: This method (available()) should not be used to determine the total size of a stream, even if the stream corresponds to a local file. Moreover, since a stream may make available more than 2^32 bytes of data, this method is incapable of expressing the entire size of the underlying data source."  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIScriptableInputStream#available()